# Power produced by a piezoelectric transducer

Tags: piezoelectricity

When we increase the size of the piezoelectric transducer will this increase the output too?

For example, a small piezoelectric disc produces 2V and makes a small LED bulb flicker or light for just a second or two.

I also want to know about the current.

The answer doesn't have to include a value just say yes or no to three questions:

1. Will the size increase the output?
2. Will it produce 1 watt in any way? (Assuming that you can adjust the conditions but only practically.)
   If it can, please give a description about what you did to make it happen.
3. What is the value of the voltage, current and power produced by the conditions you assume?

Answer (score 0):

> The answere must not include a value just say yes or no.

> WILL THE SIZE INCREASE THE OUTPUT?

No.

> WILL IT PRODUCE 1W IN ANY WAY?

No.

> HOW MUCH IS THE VALUE OF VOLT, AMPERE AND WATTS PRODUCED BY THE CONDITIONS YOU ASSUMED?

No.

(The upper bound on power out is of course power in, which is rate of change of force times distance moved; the only way to get more power out is more forceful vibration at higher speed)